# Problem with shadows when filling faces in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, faces, shadows

I've been working in blender in edit mode and I think I've accidentally activated some sort of feature with a shortcut or something.

Now every time I create a new face in edit mode, it gives that face a smudgy lightish-blackish shadow that I can't get rid off. Anyone might know what's causing it? I'm a bit lost here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have smooth shading on, right click on it (in object mode) and select "shade flat". EDIT - I just saw you're using 2.78, so that would be a left click.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!